# Deleted read messages in Sylpheed are not shown in Trash view

Tags: sylpheed

I am using Sylpheed as my email client in Kubuntu 12.04
When I delete an unread email in the inbox, it gets placed in the Trash folder.
When I delete a read email in the inbox, it gets deleted without being placed in the Trash folder.
The manual says: "Trash: in here all your deleted messages go."
Is this a bug or have I just not been able to find the setting?

Comment: Either there is some setting to auto-expunge read mails, or your view of mail in the Trash folder is set to hide read messages.

Comment: Thanks dobey, you were right with your "set to hide read messages" theory. And still, it was only by pure accident I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the message field in **Trash** view, there is a select button right next to the 'Search' field, with the options **All**, **Unread**, **Have color label** etc

These are filters for Trash view and need to be set to **All** to be able to see all deleted folder. Somehow, I had **Unread** set. Changed it to **All** solved it.

Comment: I mistook this button for search options. It was only when I came up with the idea that I could search for those illusive read messages in 'Trash' and set the option to 'All', that I realised that the button actually relates to the message field and not to 'Search'.